# How to get value from Either?

Tags: haskell

I have this code in ghci,try to decode base64 code:

```
let a=pack "MTExMTEx"
let b=decode a
:t b
b :: Either String ByteString
```

so how to get the decode bytestring from either?is there some func like Maybe's fromJust?I can't find it,thanks.

Comment: [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is really convenient to discover functions you don't know the name of by searching for the type you want.

Comment: Make sure to pick up a haskell book so you get a good grounding in the basics. In haskell the fundamental way you inspect values to "get stuff out" is through "pattern matching", either in `case` or the left-hand side of a function definition or a `let` binding, etc. If you see a type you don't understand use `:info` to print the definition. You should also make a habit to click through to the source code of the libs you're using and learn by example (click "Source" anywhere on this page for instance: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `case`:

```
case decode a of
  Left err -> {- what to do if decode gave an error -}
  Right msg -> {- what to do if decode succeeded -}
```

The `either` function that Alexandre suggests is essentially the same as this, the two branches are just taken as functions instead; i.e. it's equivalent to write:

```
either 
  (\err -> {- what to do if decode gave an error -}) 
  (\msg -> {- what to do if decode succeeded -}) 
  (decode a)
```

Comment: I agree that `fromJust` should be avoided, but since `fromRight` takes a default value to be used in the `Left` case, I don't think "throwing unrecoverable errors" is an issue. :)

Comment: Oh I just assumed I knew what `fromRight` was.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:either) function from `Data.Either`.

Its signature is:

```
either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
```

It means it takes two functions as inputs: the first one to be applied in case it's a `Left`, and the second one to be applied if it's a `Right`. The third parameter is your `Either` data type. Notice that the type of the return value of both functions must be the same.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for `Data.Either`'s [`fromRight`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:fromRight) which has a type signature

```
fromRight :: b -> Either a b -> b
```

the first value is a default value (what you'll get back if you have a `Left` instead of a `Right`.

```
fromRight 'a' (Left "b")
-- gives 'a'

fromRight 'a' (Right 'c')
-- gives 'c'
```

Comment: Note that this is a very recent addition to base. I believe you need ghc 8.2 for it.

Comment: @Carl I actually just noticed that when I went to test it and my ghc was too old!

Comment: @Carl and you're right, per [the release notes](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/8.2.1-notes.html#base) "Data.Either now provides fromLeft and fromRight"